# Take the last file and use it as jcl variable

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have to do a job that uses the last file from a base name. For example, if I am having:

FILE.140115

FILE.140111

FILE.140101

I need to catch FILE.140115 wich has the closest date from today.

So, I would use:

```
//TEST010  EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                                
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                    
//OUTDD    DD DSN=FILE.LISTFILE,                  
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                    
//            DATACLAS=(MED),                             
//            DCB=(RECFM=VB,LRECL=125)                    
//SYSIN    DD *                                           
   LISTCAT ENT(FILE.*) - 
   NAME -                                                 
   OUTFILE(OUTDD)
```

Then, using a sort I can obtain a single file with the name of the file that I need inside. But I dont know how to use the content of this file as a variable to use it as parameter in another step.

Is there a way to do this without using CLIST? Or other ways to do what I want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those are not valid datasetnames. You can't start an element with a numeric. You can use Rexx, or SORT, and either write the JCL to a dataset which is then SUBMITted or, if you are allowed to, send it to the INTRDR (Internal Reader). You can't use it as a parameter in the same JOB, as all parameters are resolved before a JOB is even selected to run. You could put the dataset-name in another dataset, and read that later and use "dynamic allocation". Depends what you know how to do.

Comment: It was an example of file, don't pay attention to that :P I was hoping to find a direct solution but as I can see it does not exist. I was trying to avoid to make a new job dynamically as a data set but well...I have not another choice. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using a GDG?  Many problems normally solved in a distributed environment with date/timestamps in file names are readily solved in a mainframe environment with GDGs.